# Parse with Regex without trailing characters

Tags: regex, parsing

How can I successfully parse the text below in that format to parse just

```
To: User <test@test.com>
```

and

```
To: <test@test.com>
```

When I try to parse the text below with

```
/To:.*<[A-Z0-9._+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}>/mi
```

It grabs

```
Message-ID <CC2E81A5.6B9%test@test.com>,
```

which I dont want in my answer.

I have tried using $ and \z and neither work.  What am I doing wrong?

**Information to parse**

```
To: User <test@test.com> Message-ID <CC2E81A5.6B9%test@test.com>
To:

<test@test.com>
```

This is my parsing information in Rubular http://rubular.com/r/DQMQC4TQLV

Comment: Maybe this is what you want? `/To:[^<]*<[^>]*>/i`? A lot of assumptions are made here, though. http://rubular.com/r/kNzjoSNyN0

Comment: Wow I have been going about this all wrong.  That is exactly what I need.  Thank you so much.  Can you please put that as the answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified exactly what your tool/language is, assumptions must be made.

In general regex pattern matching tends to be aggressive, matching the longest possible pattern.  Your pattern starts off with `.*`, which means that you're going to match the longest possible string that ENDS WITH the remainder of your pattern `<[A-Z0-9._+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}>`, which was matched with `<CC2E81A5.6B9%test@test.com>` from the `Message-ID`.

Both Apalala's and nhahtdh's comments give you something to try.  Avoid the all-inclusive `.*` at the start and use something that's a bit more specific: match leading spaces, or match anything EXCEPT the first part of what you're really interested in.

Comment: Can you explain what [^<]*<[^>]*> is doing?  I really dont follow although the answer is probably the best I could have.

Comment: The `[^<]` matches any character except `<`.  It follows that `[^<]*` matches any sequence of characters that doesn't include `<`.  The remainder of his pattern simply picks up everything between that first set of angle brackets.

Comment: Thank you.  I am going to conclude that  nhahtdh's answer is the best but you explain it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the wildcard match non greedy by adding a question mark after it:

```
To:.*?<[A-Z0-9._+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}>
```

Comment: That makes complete sense to me.